# SSL certificate for docker container

Tags: asp.net, docker, ssl

I create SSL certificate with certbot follow this article
https://www.domainesia.com/panduan/cara-install-lets-encrypt-di-vps/
and then, I want to use SSL for my docker container too, following this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0
but now I got ERR_INVALID_CERT at port 8081, but the main domain works fine